# How to get latitude and longitude on mysql database with autocomplete

Tags: php, google-maps

I Have data base

```
INSERT INTO `destination` (`destination_id`, `destination`, `latLng_lat`, `latLng_lng`)
VALUES
(3, 'Negara, Bali, Indonesia', -8.314990, 114.602493),
(4, 'Singapore', 1.352083, 103.819839),
(5, 'Jalan Negara, Mengwi, Bali, Indonesia', -8.606583, 115.194794),
(6, 'Bali, Indonesia', -8.409518, 115.188919),
(7, 'Jalan Raya Kuta, Kuta, Bali, Indonesia', -8.715054, 115.181091),
(8, 'Denpasar, Bali, Indonesia', -8.656290, 115.222099),
(9, 'Tabanan, Bali, Indonesia', -8.545040, 115.119957);
```

And now i want to select data with latLng_lat and latLng_lng
Example Search with 
"Bali, Indonesia" 
`latLng_lat=-8.4095178 and latLng_lng=115.188916`

I want show result

```
(3, 'Negara, Bali, Indonesia', -8.314990, 114.602493),
(5, 'Jalan Negara, Mengwi, Bali, Indonesia', -8.606583, 115.194794),
(6, 'Bali, Indonesia', -8.409518, 115.188919),
(7, 'Jalan Raya Kuta, Kuta, Bali, Indonesia', -8.715054, 115.181091),
(8, 'Denpasar, Bali, Indonesia', -8.656290, 115.222099),
(9, 'Tabanan, Bali, Indonesia', -8.545040, 115.119957);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE clause instead of = in query string, so that it may search rows started from the string you searched

Something similar to this :  latLng_lat LIKE '%8' and latLng_lng LIKE '%115'

Ref link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM destination WHERE destination like '%Bali, Indonesia%'
```

Comment: I can not use like,
if I do a search using the "Badung"
latLng_lat=-8.5819296 and latLng_lng=115.1770586

i want result 
(7, 'Jalan Raya Kuta, Kuta, Bali, Indonesia', -8.715054, 115.181091)

all area in Badung show

Comment: how come you search using Badung the expected result would be Bali ? I don't understand what you're really achieve?

Comment: but I couldn't find any relation that you specified.